# How to get the current time in a WPF game? (No XNA)

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, timer

I am trying to make a small game like app that has some interaction, but need an accurate enough time to evaluate the game.

I saw some java versions using this method called `System.nanoTime`.

Is there a .NET version for it?

More importantly I am looking for a some sort of timer that I can use to evaluate the world. Should I be using an actual timer control and subscribe to it?

Also the game evaluates on a different thread than the UI thread. Just in case this makes a difference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

System.Threading.Timer has a 1ms resolution.  If you need a higher resolution you can p/invoke QueryPerformanceFrequency() and QueryPerformanceCounter() in kernel32.dll

Answer (score 5):

`DateTime.Now` does not have an actual resolution in the nanosecond range. A Tick is a 100 nanosecond "chunk" of time but `DateTime.Now` **does not resolve each Tick**. I believe the lowest resolution for `DateTime.Now` is **10 milliseconds** or so. If you call `DateTime.Now` twice very quickly, you'll get the same answer. You'll only see it tick up after about 10 milliseconds or so, depending on where in the cycle you are calling it.

The [Stopwatch class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.aspx) has a finer resolution that `DateTime.Now`. I believe it will resolve down to the millisecond, which should hopefully give you enough resolution to determine if your game evaluation code is performing well enough.  There is a great example that contrasts Stopwatch vs. DateTime at the link provided.

Also, the Frequency field and GetTimestamp method can be used in place of the unmanaged Win32 APIs QueryPerformanceFrequency and QueryPerformanceCounter.

Comment: The stopwatch class will actually use QueryPerformanceCounter under the hood, if it is available (see the IsHighResolution field). So its usually not needed to use the Frequency field and GetTimestamp method manually.

Comment: @Gnafoo - That's what I was trying to convey. The intent of message was that you don't need (won't see benefit) from using P/Invoke on kernal32.dll. Thanks for the clarity.

Comment: @Joan Venge - You need to start marking questions as answered or people will stop answering. I think there are several outstanding right now.

Comment: @Dave: I often go back and mark them but that depends on which method gives me the result I want. I just don't want to accept something when I used a different method. That wouldn't be helpful for people who found these questions on SO, having the same problem IMO.

Comment: Just to give an example, right now for instance I am using System.Threading.Timer, not DateTime.Now because it gives me closer to what I need, as it lets me to call a method at certain intervals, as specified in my question.

Comment: @Joan Fair enough, but in order to get answers closed, a little feedback is encouraged. For example, on Boo's answer, add a comment that you're trying the System.Threading.Timer, or on mine let me know that I'm not answering your question. Based on the answers, it seems like we're all thinking of your question in one way and you mean it in another.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried

```
DateTime.Now;
```

This gives you the current time each time you call it. You could get it on two different points and subtract endtime - startime for timespan.

Answer (score 1):

Well, there is `DateTime.UtcNow` or `DateTime.Now`. However, for recurring processes, you should use one of the timer classes. The one usually used for wpf is [`DispatcherTimer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatchertimer.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

`DateTime.Now.Ticks` will get you down to 100 nanoseconds.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.ticks.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Use the `StopWatch` class, it uses QueryPerformanceCounter internally, so you have a very fine resolution. This way you do not need to pinvoke/interop.